# How can i search for phonetic word in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, phonetics

I have a table named Employee which contains column title and ID.

| id | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IHR Notification: Myanmar reported |
| 2 | Notification1: Moonmar reported with 3 cases |

now I want to search for phonetic word Myanmar but soundex function fails because it won't be able to convert some special character into its special code.

can any one suggest any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You have `SOUNDEX` and `DIFFERENCE`, however, you'll need to ensure the 2 values (`'Myanmar'` and `'Moonmar'`) are in their own column/value. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f346bc23bbe8a981f6af3763c7a16541)

Comment: Perhaps [full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)? Or simple string searching with LIKE, CHARINDEX, PATIINDEX, etc.?